# Move seaborn clustermap row_colors bar to the other side of the plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

By default, the seaborn row_colors bar is on the left side of the plot. All I want to do is move it to the right side... here's some simple code to replicate the issue:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import colors, cm

matrix = np.random.randint(0,5,(5,5))
coolwarm_cm = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=10),
                                cmap='coolwarm')
lut =  lambda x: coolwarm_cm.to_rgba(x)
row_colors = np.array([lut(xi) for xi in np.arange(5)])

g = sns.clustermap(matrix,
                   row_cluster=False,
                   col_cluster=False,
                   row_colors=row_colors,
                   cmap='binary',
                   cbar_pos=None)


g.ax_heatmap.tick_params(axis='y', labelright=False,labelleft=True,
                         right=False, left=True)
```

[image: Example image]

Comment: `g.ax_row_colors` should give you the axes in question. Do you want the ticks to remain on the left or move to the right?

Comment: I've been using the g.ax_heatmap.tick_params function (see below) to edit the ticks, so I don't really care because I can always mess with those after. I just want to move the bar itself.

g.ax_heatmap.tick_params(axis='y', labelright=False,labelleft=True, right=False, left=True)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's <strike>probably</strike> definitely a cleaner way to do this. `g.ax_row_colors` returns the axes in question, which you can then modify the position of:

```
ax_row_colors = g.ax_row_colors
box = ax_row_colors.get_position()

box_heatmap = g.ax_heatmap.get_position()
ax_row_colors.set_position([box_heatmap.max[0], box.y0, box.width*1.5, box.height])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a link to some documentation for this? I couldn't find the answer to this question in the `seaborn` github code: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/matrix.py

Comment: @DavidErickson - I was mostly digging around in matplotib docs to be honest. From `dir(g)` I could tell that the axes in question were `ax_row_colors` and `ax_heatmap`. After that it was straight matplotlib. The last line seems hack-y, hence the first sentence. I'm guessing there's a fancier `Bbox` approach.